# How to Implement or where in Laravel Eloquent with post method array data?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want implement Eloquent Search in Laravel Controller, this is sample query in mysql

```
  SELECT * FROM trx_order_ecommerce WHERE city LIKE '%Depok%' OR city LIKE '%Bogor%'
```

I used POST Method to retrieve cities data,

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "Depok"
  1 => "Bogor"
  2=> ,....
]
```

This is Code in My Controller

```
$data = DataOrderEcommerce::orderBy('created_at','desc');
    if(isset($request->city_name))
            {
                $dat = $request->city_name;
                for ($i=0; $i < count($dat) ; $i++) { 
                    if($i=0){
                        $data->Where('city', 'like', '%'.$dat[$i]. '%' );
                    }
                    elseif($i>0){
                        $data->OrWhere('city', 'like', '%'.$dat[$i]. '%' );
                    }
                    else{
    
                    }
                }
               $data->get()
            }
```

But I get no data,..

Comment: Do you `->get()` your data somewhere?

Comment: yes,.. but I still not get the data

Comment: You can use `->toSql()` instead and see the query, run it in phpMyAdmin or such and make sure you get results/the query is fine

Comment: @MuamarHumaidi Why are you using `LIKE %`? Aren't you having the same city names in database as sent in request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Like this:

```
$query = DataOrderEcommerce::query();
if($request->has('city_name'))
{
$query->whereIn('city', $request->city_name);
}
$query->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
```

Comment: My pleasure...!

Comment: `->when()` is more preferable as you keep working with query-builder: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```php
$data = DataOrderEcommerce::orderByDesc('created_at')
    ->when($request->has('city_name'), function($q) use ($request)
        {
            foreach($request->city_name as $key => $city) {
                if ($key == 0) {
                    $q->where('city', 'like', '%'.$city. '%' );
                } else {
                    $q->orWhere('city', 'like', '%'.$city. '%' );
                }
            }
        })->get();
```